# Typescript Errors in Function Pushing Objects to an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to push new objects to an array in my Angular 2 app, but I am running into an issue (which I suspect may be a Typescript type issue, though I'm not certain). This is what the array I'm pushing to looks like:

```
locations = [
  { city: 'Los Angelas', postalCode: '90001', coordinates: 2321 },
  { city: 'New York', postalCode: '10001', coordinates: 3432 },
];
```

And here is the function I am using to push new zipcodes to the array with:

```
  addZipcode(event) {
    this.locations.push({ postalCode: this.newPostalCode });
    this.newPostalCode = '';
    this.addZipInput = false;
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

The error I'm getting re: this function is:

> Argument of type '{ postalCode: any; }' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type '{ city: string; postalCode: string; coordinates: number; }'. 
>   Property 'city' is missing in type '{ postalCode: any; }'.

How can I deal with this issue? Users will be pushing postalCodes, not cities or coordinates. I would think I could push an object of any kind to the array, but it seems typescript is preventing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript has inferred array type as `{ city: string; postalCode: string; coordinates: number; }[]` , but you are trying to push `{postalCode:string}` - this is error. If you still want to do this then it is necessary to set appropriate type for `location`:

```
  location:any[]
  //or
  interface ILocation {
     city?:string;
     postalCode?:string;
     coordinates?:string;
  }
  location:ILocation[];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `locations` as array of objects with optional `city` and `coordinates`:

```
type Loc = {city?: string; postalCode: string; coordinates?: number};

let locations: Loc[] = [
  { city: 'Los Angelas', postalCode: '90001', coordinates: 2321 },
  { city: 'New York', postalCode: '10001', coordinates: 3432 },
];
```